# Facebook Graph API - can't search for HashTag

Tags: .net, facebook, facebook-fql

I make the following query on Graph API explorer to search facebook hashtags:

`search?q=%23egypt&type=post`

But the response is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#11) Post search has been deprecated",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 11
  }
}
```

So, do you have any workaround for that problem, and if so how to be implemented in FB SDK?

Comment: Thnks for editing @Lal

Answer (score 4):

You should read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/ . Public post search have been deprecated and is not available anymore.

Comment: This seems crazy to me - why would you remove search? Surely there's some way they plan to expose this data. Hashtags even get special treatment in Graph search now: https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/egypt

Comment: I'm just a Software Engineer at Facebook. I did not make the decision to remove it or do I know the reason for why. I just answered @user3621206 question.

But to your comment about Graph Search. There are many many features that are available on Facebook.com that are not available in the API. And Graph Search is one of those things so I don't know why it being available in Graph Search would mean that it would be available in the API.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean "you" but "they" I guess. I still think it seems contradictory to promote hashtags through Graph Search and depreciate them in Graph API. Maybe Public Feed API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/) is intended to be the replacement?